# Python Code to Read Symbols within PDF Document

Tags: python, testing, project

I am currently working on a project where I need to complete the following. I have a singular document which has 2 pages. The first has a legend which outlines what each symbol represents (For Example an X will equal Treasure) and the second will have a map. I need the code to be able to read the legend of objects and count the occurrences of that object on the map. Is this possible? (I am fresh to python and programming in general)

I tried using some pre made models but the outcome never really worked how I needed it to. Chat GPT was also no help